# How to filter for related objects in Prisma?

Tags: prisma

How can query relationships in Prisma? I have the following schema:

```
model User {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String?
  profile Profile 
}

model Profile {
  id     Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId Int
}
```

How can I query a `Profile` for a specific `User`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

```
prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: 42 }}).profile()
```